# Get Baker Fee percent from address

Tags: baker, rewards, fee

I want to get baker fee percent(%) value of the selected baker.

I am going to calculate delegator's reward for cycle, I need to know baker fee percent, so I can get exact delegator's reward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this information on baker rating sites such as https://baking-bad.org/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it have REST api? Because, I need to use it on code

Comment: @Heindrick just look at the nav menu ;)